# Why won't it let me add songs in name space when ive added a ref

Tags: c#, unit-testing

[image]I can't add the namespace song to do some unit testing when I have added it to the refs I have closed and opened visual studio multiple times now and that isn't working.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using songs;

namespace UnitTestProject3
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Either `songs` should be capitalized or the namespace is different than the assembly name. What namespace is the `Song` class in?

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
using Songs;
```

Your case is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The name should be capitalized. You should write "using Songs".

Also it is possible that the namespace is different from the name of the assembly. In that case you need to find the name of the namespace and use that.

Comment: How do I use the name space it is grey